# MIME header appearing in the email message body

Tags: php

I have a problem sending php email using the code below. The MIME heades keep apearing in the message and the attachment appears as scribble text in the mesage body not as attachment. what could be the problem

```
        <?php
        session_start();
        require_once("includes/functions.php"); 
        require_once("includes/dbconnect.php");
        require_once("Mail/mailfunctions.php");



         //function_to_be_applied($finaldest_email, $message, $subject, $fromname, $fromemail, $replyto )
         function function_to_be_applied($finaldest_email, $key){
                //require_once "Mail.php" ;
                global $fromemail;
                global $message;
                global $fromname;
                global $subject;
                global $replyto;
                global $seconds;
                global $reprt;
                global $headers;

                $to = $finaldest_email;
                $from = "".$fromname." <$fromemail>";
                $subject = $subject;

                if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
                                            sleep($seconds);
                $reprt .= "Message successfully sent to: ". $to."<br />";
                                    } else {
                $reprt .= "Message not successfully sent to: ". $to."<br />";
                                    }

                }

         if(isset($_POST['submit']))
          { 
            $errors_val = array();
            $required_fields = array("subject", "fromemail", "message", "dest_email"); 
            foreach($required_fields as $fieldname)
            {
                 if( !isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || ( empty($_POST[$fieldname]) &&(!is_int($_POST[$fieldname])) ))
                       {
                        if($fieldname == "subject")
                          {$errors_val[0] = "-Sending email without SUBJECT is not allowed";}
                        if($fieldname == "fromemail")
                          {$errors_val[1] = "-Sending email without a FROM EMAIL is not allowed";}
                        if($fieldname == "message")
                          {$errors_val[2] = "-Sending an empty message is not allow";} 
                        if($fieldname == "dest_email")
                          {$errors_val[3] = "-There must be at least one email in the destination email address";}

                        }
            }
            if(empty($errors_val)){
            $errors = array();
            if(false == validate_email(trim($_POST['fromemail']))){
              $errors[0] = "FROM EMAIL is invalid";
            }
            if(false == validate_email(trim($_POST['replyto']))){
              $errors[1] = "REPLY TO EMAIL is invalid";}
            if(!is_numeric(trim($_POST['seconds']))){
              $errors[2] = "Seconds between messages must be a number";}

            $allowtypes = array("doc", "pdf", "txt", "zip", "gif", "jpeg", "jpg"); //the type of file can be attached
            $max_file_size="100"; //describes the size that cab be attached

            // checks that we have a file
            if((!empty($_FILES["attachment"])) && ($_FILES["attachment"]["error"] == 0)) {
               //set a variable $attached = 1
                    $attached = 1;

                    // basename -- Returns filename component of path
                    $filename = basename($_FILES['attachment']['name']);
                    $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
                    $filesize=$_FILES['attachment']['size'];
                    $max_bytes=$max_file_size*1024;

                    //Check if the file type uploaded is a valid file type. 
                    if (!in_array($ext, $allowtypes)) {
                        $errors[3]="Invalid extension for your file: <strong>".$filename."</strong>";
                        unset($attached);
                // check the size of each file
                } elseif($filesize > $max_bytes) {
                        $errors[4]= "Your file: <strong>".$filename."</strong> is to big. Max file size is ".$max_file_size."kb.";
                     unset($attached);
                        }

            } 

        if(empty($errors)){
                  //generate a unique boundary
                  $semi_rand = md5(time());
                  $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

                  if(isset($_POST['seconds']) && ($_POST['seconds'] != ""))
                  {$seconds = $_POST['seconds'];}else{$seconds = 0.5;}
                  $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
                  $fromname = trim($_POST['fromname']);
                  $fromemail = trim($_POST['fromemail']);
                  $from = stripslashes($fromname)."<".stripslashes($fromemail).">";
                  $emailmessage  = trim($_POST['message']);
                  $replyto = trim($_POST['replyto']);
                  $dest_email = trim($_POST['dest_email']);
                  $emailarray = explode("\r\n", $dest_email, 400);
                  $finaldest_email = array_unique($emailarray );

                  $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
                  $headers .= "Reply-To:" . $replyto . "\r\n";
                  $headers .= "Mime-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                  $headers .= " Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
                              " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";


                  //attachment 
              if(isset($attached)){
                  $fileatt      = $_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"];
                  $fileatt_type = $_FILES["attachment"]["type"];
                  $fileatt_name = $_FILES["attachment"]["name"];
                if (is_uploaded_file($fileatt)) {
                  // Read the file to be attached ('rb' = read binary)
                  $data =  file_get_contents($fileatt);

                  //$file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
                  //$data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
                  //fclose($file);

                  // Base64 encode the file data
                  $finaldata = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
                   }
                    $message  = "--{$mime_boundary}\r\n";
                    $message .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
                    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
                    $message .= "{$emailmessage}\r\n";
                    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\r\n";
                    $message .= "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type}; name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n\n".
                              "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n";
                    $message .=  "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n\n";

                    $message .= "{$finaldata} \r\n--{$mime_boundary}--\r\n";

               }elseif(!isset($attached)){

                    $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\r\n";
                    $message .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\" \r\n";
                    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
                    $message .= "{$emailmessage}\r\n";
                    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--\r\n";

                    }
                $reprt = "Preparing to send message..<br />";

          if( true == array_walk($finaldest_email, 'function_to_be_applied' )){
          $numberofemailsent = count($finaldest_email);

          }else{echo "No email sent";}

               }else{$string = implode("<br /> -" , $errors);  $error_message = $string; }



            }else{$string = implode("<br /> -" , $errors_val);  $error_message = $string; }



         }

          ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't generate your own mime emails. Use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) or [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) and reduce a huge chunk of that script down to maybe 10 lines of code.

As well, don't verify file types by looking at filenames. It's trivial to forge a filename AND the client-specified mime type. Always use server-side mime verification instead.

Comment: I have found the cause. the header was not properly crafted